# plotlyOutput with geom_bar not showing negative values

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Consider the following very simple example:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- data.frame(SomeX = c("Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3"),
                   SomeFill = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), 
                   SomeY = c(2, 3, 4, -4, 7, 3))

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplot(df, aes(x = SomeX, y = SomeY, fill=SomeFill)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For some reason it does not show the value -4 properly in the output. It shows the value as if it was +4. This is different from the result from the code (using plot rather than plotly):

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- data.frame(SomeX = c("Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3"),
                   SomeFill = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), 
                   SomeY = c(2, 3, 4, -4, 7, 3))

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(df, aes(x = SomeX, y = SomeY, fill=SomeFill)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's a bug, see https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/560

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotly has some issues with negative values in stacked bars. If you define the plot directly via `plot_ly` and use `barmode = 'relative'`, it should work.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("event")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- data.frame(SomeX = c("Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3"),
                   SomeFill = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), 
                   SomeY = c(2, 3, 4, -4, 7, 3))

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(df, x=~SomeX, y=~SomeY, color=~SomeFill, type='bar') %>% layout(barmode = 'relative')
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. That solves it. I hoped there would be a way with plotly (simply because I use it everywhere else) but if that's not the case plot_ly will certainly get the job done.